# How do I diplay data received from websocket without using state

Tags: reactjs, websocket

the data from the websocket is real time.
I've done it using state but problem there is by using state component re-renders a lot.
Note:I am trying to make crypto ticker app, something like binance or wazirx that shows real time data of any crypto coin.

Comment: If you don't use state, don't want to re-render the component, how do you display the data in the component?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using socket.io you can use this hook it manage connection to not create new socket each time component re-render (for exemple you can use it in your main component then pass it in props)
https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-react-hook